# Help with Plymouth script please! :)

Tags: boot, scripts, raid, plymouth

I am attempting to work around this problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997417

on the hypothesis that the problem is a race condition between the boot sequence and '/' and my raid0 disks being available [I don't know that it is, but would like to see if that the case.]

I read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth, and have:
* played with plymouth-x11 [very nice]
* installed plymouth-theme-script

I would like to do something like this in my boot process, so Plymouth waits for the user's input before continuing:

Code:

Show the splash screen

```
sudo plymouth show-splash
```

Stop the graphical progress indicator

```
sudo plymouth pause-progress
```

Display a message

```
sudo plymouth message --text="pausing boot - press 'c' or space bar to continue"
```

Wait for the user to type either 'c', 'C' or space (no return required)

```
sudo plymouth watch-keystroke --keys="cC " --command="tee /tmp/c_key_pressed"
```

Change the on-screen message

```
sudo plymouth message --text="resuming boot"
```

Resume the graphical progress indicator

```
sudo plymouth unpause-progress
```

But I don't really know how to proceed safely.

I'm an IDOIT, so would appreciate an IDIOT-proof guide

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your actual question is?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with your plymouth script, but I can suggest another solution, which you may or may not find satisfactory.
I have this same problem with degraded raid, I simply opted to always boot a degraded raid.

```
sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm
```

and set `BOOT_DEGRADED=yes`

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer Jorge in thread so here goes.

The real issue here is that usplash does not allow for errors requiring human interaction, so in this case mdadm is throwing up an error saying that the raid has been degraded do you wish to mount the degraded array [Y/N].

But you can not see or answer the question because usplash is preventing you from doing so (this may be a nvidia only problem). So boot hangs indefinitely. Upon reboot you can choose to go into recovery mode because the last boot failed. At which point you can hit Y and boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have checked your method against what I have already tried: sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdadm, which sets BOOT_DEGRADED=true in the file you mentioned. Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Is there perhaps something I need to run after having set BOOT_DEGRADED=true?

Comment: I'm getting a sneaking suspicion that the answer lies in this thread [as a matter of fact I am getting tingles up my spine, it is so familiar] http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861516&page=2

Comment: made the edit and about to try a few reboots!!!

Comment: hmm, I probably had run sudo update-initramfs after I made the edit. Was a few weeks ago so I can't remember

Comment: O.M.G GIVE THIS MAN A MEDAL!!!!! - SOLVED!!! dangriffin in this thread posted the correct answer: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861516&page=2

Comment: 3/3 successful boots, where previously I had nothing

Comment: Seems that there was a bug in 11.10 which perhaps did not get reported as such, and is still there in 12.04.

Comment: And to think I was about to try hacking plymouth, when the culprit was in initramfs - but it WAS a race condition. I believe I might have seen something remotely similar in 8.04 ...

Comment: Awesome, this bug need reporting if it isn't already as it was very very frustrating for me too.

Comment: Just to be clear, the dpkg-reconfigure mdadm would not have solved the issue, it was instead hacking the code in the mdadm functions in initramfs which did it. Well done, dangriffin!